# How are warps partitioned across cores in NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

There are many posts about how CUDA threads and blocks get mapped to GPU hardware, but I cannot find a clear answer to this question. What are the rules by which warps are partitioned across cores, if any?

I know that multiprocessors containing  some number of cores each receive one or several thread blocks to process. These blocks are partitioned into warps (32 threads each), and then deployed to different cores, but  what are the rules by which warps are then mapped to cores? Is it always one warp per core, or something else? Can a core process several warps? Fractions of a warp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA cores are integer/floating point math pipelines and as such the partitioning implied by the term core is deceiving. Each SM has 1-4 warp schedulers. Each warp scheduler has a fixed number of dispatch units. Each dispatch unit can dispatch to specific pipelines which include CUDA cores (int/fp), double precision units, load store units, branch units, special function units, and texture units. The pipelines can have different widths which can be determined by the pipeline throughput. All threads in a warp are issued to the same pipeline. The instruction may be issued over multiple cycles.

The GPU pipelines are fairly deep. Only one warp can be at a given stage of a specific pipeline; however, multiple warps may be active in the pipeline. For example, warp 1 may be in ALU.execute and warp 2 may be in ALU.write_back stages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So then, within an SM, any given warp can potentially be dispatched to any pipeline (texture units, cores, etc...) on the SM? There is no parallel-partitioning of hardware resources on the SM across warps or groups of warps?

Comment: Each warp scheduler has dispatch units that can dispatch to specific pipelines. Warps allocated to a specific warp scheduler cannot use integer/fp pipelines of a different warp scheduler. Some pipelines such as the load store unit are shared by all warp schedulers.

Comment: Different pipeline widths? So each pipeline can execute multiple instructions in a superscalar fashion? Does that mean if I have 32 FP32 cores, I can have more than 32 instructions issued to the FP32 pipelines in the same cycle?

Comment: The math execution units are pipelined and support superscalar execution. Instructions are issued 1 warp at a time. Based upon the depth of the pipeline more than 1 warp instruction may be in flight at a time.

Answer (score 1):

All warps from the same block run on the same SM.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But each SM consists of multiple cores, correct? My question was, how many warps are sent to each core? And does a core always process whole numbers of warps?